# Phi combinator in Scala

Tags: scala, combinators

Is there a Phi combinator (also known as [`on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) function from Haskell) in Scala?

Answer (score 3):

Not that I'm aware of but it's fairly easy to implement. For instance:

```scala
def on[A, B](f: A => B)(combine: (B, B) => B): (A, A) => B =
  (x: A, y: A) => combine(f(x), f(y))
```

Comment: `combine` output shouldn't be exactly `B`, so can be rewritten as `(B, B) => C`